# Draw scatterplot of class results in exam

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to draw a scatterplot which shows the percentage of marks gained for each student per question, and calculate the averages for the whole class.

```
maxmarks.paper <- c(4,5,2,4,3,4,5,4,6,3,3,5,3,4,4,4,3,3,2,5,4)

results.student1 <- c(4,3,2,3,3,4,5,4,3,3,0,0,2,4,1,1,2,0,1,0,0)
results.student2 <- c(2,2,0,4,1,1,0,1,4,2,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,1,1,0)
#etc.

percentage1 <- results.student1 / maxmarks.paper * 100
percentage2 <- results.student2 / maxmarks.paper * 100
#etc.
```

I was looking at [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_scatterplots.htm) tutorial, but I do not understand how this works.

```
plot(x = "questions 1:20", y= "percentage of marks gained per student" ...)
```

Can someone help plot the scattergraph?

Comment: You don't understand what? The whole thing? Be specific please. You need a more detailed tutorial.

Comment: How to plot the graph

Comment: What should the graph look like? What variable are you trying to put on the x axis and what on the y axis? And what do you want to do with the averages?

Comment: @efbbrown see edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to show the percentage mark of **each** question, for **each** student. You need to plot multiple lines on the same graph.

Following on from **efbbrown**'s answer, (to store the `results` and calculate percentages more effectively).

```
maxmarks.paper <- c(4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 6, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 5, 4)

# Input the results as a data frame rather than individual vectors
results <- data.frame(
  student1 = c(4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 0, 0, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0),
  student2 = c(2, 2, 0, 4, 1, 1, 0, 1, 4, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
)

# Calculate the percentages all at once instead of repeating the equation 
over and over
percentages <- data.frame(apply(results, 2, function(student) {
    return(student / maxmarks.paper * 100)
}))
```

Now to plot the graph:

```
plot (x = 1:21, y = percentages$student1, type = "p", xlab = "Questions in paper", ylab = "Class Average (%)")
```

The `type = "p"` parameter will draw only the dots, to add another vector, use the `lines` function.

```
lines(x = 1:21, y = percentages$student2, type = "p", xlab = "Questions in paper", ylab = "Class Average (%)")
```

You can run this for each student to add their percentages to the graph. To calculate the average for all students use:

```
# from efbbrown's answer
percentages$class.average <- apply(percentages, 1, mean)
```

You can then add that to the graph using:

```
lines(x = 1:21, y = percentages$class.average, type = "l", xlab = "Questions in paper", ylab = "Class Average (%)")
```

`type = "l"` will show only the line, similarly `type = "o"` will show both line and dots.

The above will look like this:
[image: scatterplot]

Answer (score 1):

OK here is your code expressed in a more succinct way and a plot of what I *think* your asking for, though still not entirely clear:

```
maxmarks.paper <- c(4,5,2,4,3,4,5,4,6,3,3,5,3,4,4,4,3,3,2,5,4)

# Input the results as a data frame rather than individual vectors
results <- data.frame(
  student1 = c(4,3,2,3,3,4,5,4,3,3,0,0,2,4,1,1,2,0,1,0,0),
  student2 = c(2,2,0,4,1,1,0,1,4,2,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,1,1,0)
)

# Calculate the percentages all at once instead of repeating the equation over and over
percentages <- data.frame(apply(results, 2, function(student) {
  return(student / maxmarks.paper * 100)
}))

# Calculate the class average on each question and store it in the same table
percentages$class_average <- apply(percentages, 1, mean)

# Plot the average mark for each question and label the axes
plot(x = 1:21, y = percentages$class_average, xlab = "Questions 1:21", ylab = "Class Average (%)", pch = 19)

# Add points to the chart for each student
for (i in 1:2) {
  points(x = 1:21, y = percentages[[paste0("student", i)]], col = "green", pch = 19)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't want *just* the average. I need to draw multiple dots on every question (on the y-axis) as the percentage of every student (approx 30 in total). As an example can you show me how to draw just the two.

Comment: This is more complex and requires ggplot2. It also has implications for efficient structuring of your data. Try this using your sample data:
 `df <- data.frame(maxmarks.paper, results.student1, results.student2)
names(df) <-  c("max", "st1", "st2")

df <- df %>% mutate(pc1 = st1/max * 100, pc2 = st2/max * 100, q = 1:21) %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(avg = mean(c(pc1, pc2), na.rm = TRUE))

ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = q, y = pc1)) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = q, y = pc2)) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = q, y = avg, color = "red"))`

Comment: Hey @User I added a few more lines to add points for each student

Answer (score 0):

With this formula, you can draw a scatterplot comparing each pair of students, e.g.

```
plot(x = results.student1, y = results.student2)
```

To calculate averages across the class, you need to sum up the data per question. For scatterplots, you use exactly two variables; if you have 20 questions, you will only be able to do it for each pair of questions.

Comment: I need to compare multiple students, there are approximately 30 in total.